# Double variable value is equal NaN

Tags: c#, variables

I have the following code in c#

```
double sum1= 0; 
double sum2=0; 
sum1=(a*b-bb*t1); 
sum2= (a*c-cc)*(a*t2-t3); 
Double fs1=  sum1/Math.Sqrt(sum2);
```

Where the values of the double variables are

```
a=19999
b=65445.370449999828
c=41.054005875599991
bb= 126053.41368000521
cc=15889463100.382524
t1=9999.0
t2=9999.0
t3=99980001.0
```

Why I got value NaN for the double variable fs1, but when I calculate the same equation above in Microsoft Excel I got value equal to 0.779331833

Comment: `sum2` is negative, but you're trying to take the square root of it

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere maybe. Because your `sum2` is calculated as a negative value, and you cannot take square root of a negative number as a `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Sqrt(sum2)` returns `NaN` because `sum2` is negative

```
sum1 / NaN = NaN
```

If you want to get value anyway do this:

```
Double fs1 =  sum1/Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(sum2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `sum2` will be `-1,58870531971129E+18` and [`Math.Sqrt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt.aspx) returns [`NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx) for `Negative` values.

That's why your `fs1` will be `48433880,2431746 / NaN` and `double / NaN` returns `NaN`.

Read: [7.7.2 Division operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for all posts. Actully. this is the linear correlation between two double arrays. if i use the Abs inside the Sqrt, the final results will change.

Comment: @MehdiAcademic2014 Yes becuase `Abs` gets positive value of it and result will not be `NaN` anymore.